get : The term 'get' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program
i have a problem with GetX FLutter when i try to write this in terminal: "get create page:register"
the error:
get : The term 'get' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

get create page:register

  + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (get:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException





please help me
i have tried flutter pub global activate get_cli but it doesn't work

Use this command instead:
flutter pub global activate --source=git https://github.com/inyong1/get_cli.git

You may benefit from this article.
